# ESP8266 GET request sent but not received by website

Tags: http, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I am trying to send a GET request with Arduino Uno using ESP8266. The final goal is to send data from arduino and save them in a mysql database. I can manually send data to it using my browser. However, I am not able to send data from Arduino to PHP.

Here is my code:

```
AT+CIPMUX=0 --> OK
AT+CWMODE=1 --> OK
AT+CIPSTART="TCP","issamdata.alwaysdata.net",80 -->OK
AT+CIPSEND=49 --> OK
GET /saveData.php?date=23-02-2020&home=1 HTTP/1.0  
-->  busy s... 
-->  Recv 49 bytes
-->  SEND OK
```

But then when i check my database there is nothing there, i tried to send a GET request with postman and it works just fine.

i also tried to put the full link after GET like this: "GET http://issamdata.alwaysdata.net/saveData.php?date=23-02-2020&home=1 HTTP/1.0" it didn't work either.

Comment: read the HTML response. you should get +IPD with the response

Comment: Can you please explain to me how to read the HTML response? am i supposed to get a response under "SEND OK" ?

Comment: SEND OK si only confirmation of CIPSEND. print everything received from AT firmware

Comment: I printed everything, SEND OK is the last line

Comment: and do you read Serial after that?

Comment: I'm using the serial monitor, and there is no +IPD after SEND OK

Comment: does your code after CIPSEND read the Serial where esp8266 is wired?

Comment: i don't think so

Comment: then you can't see the response